# Oracle union capturing all the values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that has one column called PEGA ID that column has values 111, 222 etc and some 0's as well, when i do the qry below all the 0's are filtered how can i count those 0's also , can i use union?

```
SELECT  
    ivr.dw_dealer_id, 
    ivr.dw_product_id, 
    ivr.dw_program_type_id, 
    ivr.dw_month_id, 
    TO_CHAR(ivr_update_dt, 'YYYYMM') buss_month, 
    count(*)
FROM  idm_ivr_interaction ivr, stgdba.interactions intr
WHERE ivr.cti_rec_id = intr.pega_id
```

Comment: Do you mean 0 or *null*? What data type are the columns *cti_rec_id* and *pega_id*?

Comment: Btw can you plese show us the table and some sample data please, even better if you can give us expected output too.. anyway how do you run an aggregated query in oracle without a `group by`?

Comment: I have group by but i just didn't pasted it here, sorry for the confusion

Comment: expected out put will be all the records count from stgdba.interactions intr table including pega id's 0 but right now with a join between stgdba.interactions intr and idm_ivr_interaction ivr all the pega id's with 0's are getting filtered.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Since OP specifically mentioned it's a `0` not a null, we change the query to use `case`.

`count(case when ivr.dw_dealer_id = 0 then 1 else ivr.dw_dealer_id end)`

Or just use the query with last `OR`.

```
SELECT  
        ivr.dw_dealer_id, 
        ivr.dw_product_id, 
        ivr.dw_program_type_id, 
        ivr.dw_month_id, 
        TO_CHAR(ivr_update_dt, 'YYYYMM') buss_month, 
        count(ivr.dw_dealer_id) as counts
    FROM  idm_ivr_interaction ivr, stgdba.interactions intr
    WHERE ivr.cti_rec_id = intr.pega_id
    AND (intr.pega_id IS NULL OR ivr.cti_rec_id IS NULL)
```

---

Wrapping `nvl` around the id...

```
SELECT  
    ivr.dw_dealer_id, 
    ivr.dw_product_id, 
    ivr.dw_program_type_id, 
    ivr.dw_month_id, 
    TO_CHAR(ivr_update_dt, 'YYYYMM') buss_month, 
    count(nvl(ivr.dw_dealer_id,1))
FROM  idm_ivr_interaction ivr, stgdba.interactions intr
WHERE ivr.cti_rec_id = intr.pega_id
AND (intr.pega_id IS NULL OR ivr.cti_rec_id IS NULL)
```

- BTW there should be a `Group By`... with the `count` you are using.......

Comment: Value for pega is is not null it is 0

Comment: Then we use `CASE` Can you try the above editted query and comment please? :)

Comment: I am not following it in count(case when ivr.dw_dealer_id = 0 then 1 else ivr.dw_dealer_id) as counts
You are saying that when ivr.dw_dealer_id is 0, but we don;t have case like that, we have intr.pega_id =0 in interactions table

Comment: Can you please show your tables? It's much easier that way. Otherwise it's a bit blind guesss... :$ Remove that case totally and just try with two `is null` lines that I added with OR.

Comment: SELECT dw_dealer_id, -1 as dw_product_id, dw_program_type_id, dw_month_id, TO_CHAR(cti.buss_dt, 'YYYYMM') buss_month, count(nvl(intr.pega_id,1)) FROM idm_cti_call_dtl cti, stgdba.interactions intr,idm_month_dim md WHERE cti.cti_rec_id =intr.pega_id AND (intr.pega_id IS NULL OR cti.cti_rec_id IS NULL) AND TRUNC(cti.buss_dt) between 'DD-MON-YYYY' and 'DD-MON-YYYY' AND TO_CHAR(cti.buss_dt, 'YYYYMM') = md.clndr_YYYYMM GROUP BY TO_CHAR(cti.buss_dt, 'YYYYMM'), dw_month_id, dw_dealer_id, dw_product_id, dw_program_type_id